# How can I choose random items and write them in flutter

Tags: flutter, random

I create a specific pattern about persons and i have several persons how can i choose randomly and write it in specific pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your persons to a list and get random number 0 to size of list, pick item with random number

```
import 'dart:math';
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(<list_size>); // from 0 to list_size-1
```

get list[randomNumber]

Comment: Thx i got it but how can write it in specific pattern for example (name:  surname:  age:)

Comment: could you give me an example of a spesific pattern because i didn't understand what do you mean

Comment: So do you want to pick name, surname and age from different users or write them in different order? @Tyakona

Comment: On mine pattern i have three container for each description name surname and age i want to add random name surname and age for each one

Comment: @Tyakona then you can choose 3 random number, pick name with first one, pick surname with second one, and pick age with last one

Comment: Okey i got it thx -Sağol Abicim-

Comment: you're welcome bro, if it's works for you mark as accepted @Tyakona